# Tag wildcard search compiles into an incorrect search

Tags: bug, tags, search

Suppose I search with the following query:

> [c#] [regex] [string*]

I would expect the results to be: any question tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), as well as any tag beginning with 'string'.

However, the [actual search this compiles down to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string+or+string-formatting+or+stringbuilder+or+string-comparison+or+string-concatenation+or+string-matching+or+stringstream+or+string-parsing+or+string-array+or+string-literals+or+stringtokenizer+or+replace+or+string.format+or+stringtemplate+or+string-length+or+stringformat+or+stringbuffer+or+stringify+or+string-split+or+string-interpolation+c%23+regex) turns into a giant block of *or* statements, and the results don't necessarily include [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) or [regex](/questions/tagged/regex). Those two tags are added onto the end, and I wonder if it ends up returning any string* tag, but only those [string-interpolation](/questions/tagged/string-interpolation) questions which are also tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [regex](/questions/tagged/regex).

[image]

Could this be fixed, so that a search like this will behave as expected, and include only questions with the wildcarded tags if they also match the other tags in the search query?